# How do you confirm your background service has closed?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am knew to Android, Java, and the Eclipse IDE. I am running two services in the background of my app and I think I am closing them correctly, but I want to make sure. One starts and stops during use the other ends when the app does. How do you confirm that the service has indeed closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onDestroy() method along with a Toast message:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Tell the user we have ended.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed/stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```